# Date manipulation and SQL datetime WHERE queries

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

So I'm about ready to drive my car off a bridge and really need an outside opinion on how to do this, I have been struggling for days to find any kind of valid solution and feel as though it's simply all my pent up stress holding me back. That being said any help is appreciated.

Preface:
My application handles customers in a sql database and users can select a customer and upload an appointment to another table. Yes this is homework, and yes I have attempted to solve it myself. I have hit a mental block and can't get anywhere on it, which is why I really need someone to clue me into what I am doing wrong.

Where I am running into serious mental blocks is converting the dates properly, as well as querying the SQL. I am using **JavaFX datepicker, which returns a Date() in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD'**, example for today would be '2018-25-11'. Appointments are stored in UTC, which leads me to my first problem.

*If an employee selects a date, say December 1st, 2018, this date needs to be converted to UTC and the full 24 hours need to be queried from the database.*

Question 1:
So my idea was get the Date() object from datepicker which is in the above form, then adding " 00:00:00" to it and attempting to convert to UTC, but I have no idea how to do this and can't find anything relevant, how would you go about doing this. I also need tomorrows date at '00:00:00'converted so that I can get a full range of possible UTC times to query

Here's my attempt at question 1 with output:

```
//I live in PST, which is UTC-8
test("2018-12-01");

private static void test(String date){
    try{
        DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date startDate = utcFormat.parse(date + " 00:00:00");
        System.out.println(startDate);

        LocalDateTime today = convertToLocalDateTimeViaSqlTimestamp(startDate);
        today = today.plusDays(1);

        System.out.println(convertToDateViaSqlTimestamp(today));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private static Date convertToDateViaSqlTimestamp(LocalDateTime dateToConvert) {
    return java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(dateToConvert);
}
private static LocalDateTime convertToLocalDateTimeViaSqlTimestamp(Date dateToConvert) {
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(dateToConvert.getTime()).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Fri Nov 30 16:00:00 PST 2018
2018-12-01 16:00:00.0
```

I have re-read over our class material and it contains nothing on the above. I have contacted/tried to meet up with my professor during office hours and he is never available even during his mandated times. I have a fully working program and the last thing that is holding me back is my inability to find any useful solution to above.

Question 2:
The database holds a start business time, in UTC just for simplicity say its "00:00:00" and extends 8 hours so the end time would be "08:00:00", how do I return all appointment entries that fall between these times from question 2, assuming the start/end times are in datetime format.

Here's what I did for question 2, I would like to know if this is acceptable given that I know that the exact format for dates will always be in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format or will it fail in some obscure condition?:

```
SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE start >= '2018-12-01 00:00:00' AND end < '2018-12-01 02:00:00';
```

Comment: Never silently swallow exceptions `catch(Exception e){

    }
`

Comment: It's only for testing, the above method is not in my application but an attempt to figure out how to solve question 1. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question

if you have the start and end column as datetime and want  to be sure that the string values  match  in mysql can use STR_TO_DATE for build a proper datetime

eg assuming your datetime is in the format 2018-12-01 00:00:00

you could

```
SELECT * 
FROM appointment 
WHERE start >= str_to_date('2018-12-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T')  AND 
        end < str_to_date('2018-12-01 02:00:00',  '%Y-%m-%d %T');
```

and For first question yiu could take a look at
convert_tz() function  so you could do all the work using a query

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for the information! If noone responds with a method to achieve what I need in my first question I'll make sure to mark this as the answer in a couple days. I really need help with the first part, it is what has been really ruining my week.

Comment: @Joe  for the first question i have added  a brief suggestion